# How to change language of android app ? Locale is deprecated

Tags: java, android, locale

I have just finalized my app but getting this error on a method which changes language of app

```
Setting.java:uses or overrides a deprecated API.Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

here is my method

```
private void setLanguage(String language){

    //setting new configuration
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    con.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);

    //store current language in prefrence
    prefData.setCurrentLanguage(language);

    //With new configuration start activity again
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}
```

how can I overcome this issue and publish my app. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
config.locale = locale;
```

is deprecated starting from Android.N, so use below code:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        config.setLocale(locale);
    } else {
        config.locale = locale;
    }
```

plus the best way to restart an activity is to call:

```
recreate();
```

Comment: warning is still there

Comment: Warning is fine as long as you are checking and making sure it will not fail on different devices. The warning is there because you are still calling the deprecated method, this will be resolved at runtime when the condition is checked.

Comment: If you are still worried, you can suppress it, see my updated answer

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue .This is worked for me.

```
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration  conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.setLocale(new Locale("es"));
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```